# c# HTTPS proxy (just relaying from browser -> proxy -> website -> proxy -> browser)

Tags: c#, https, proxy

so I have this code where I relay all connections to the destination server, I get the response back from it in a byte[] called result, but when dealing with SSL/HTTPS the end server always return an empty response

```
public static byte[] ForwardRequest(byte[] requestBytes)
    {
        byte[] result = new byte[0];

        try
        {
            string requestString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(requestBytes);
            string[] requestLines = requestString.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);

            string host = "";
            int port = 80;

            if (requestString.Contains("CONNECT"))
            {
                string connectLine = requestLines[0];
                string hostWithPort = connectLine.Split(' ')[1];
                host = hostWithPort.Split(':')[0];
                port = Convert.ToInt32(hostWithPort.Split(':')[1]);
            }
            else
            {
                host = requestLines[1].Split(' ')[1];
                if (host.Contains(":"))
                {
                    string[] split = host.Split(':');
                    host = split[0];
                    port = Convert.ToInt32(split[1]);
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("HOST:" + host + "#PORT:" + port);

            TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
            client.Connect(host, port);

            if(client.Connected == true && requestString.Contains("CONNECT"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("client connected to ssl");
            }

            Network.WriteBytes(client, requestBytes);
            result = Network.ReadBytes(client, 10000);


            if (requestString.Contains("CONNECT"))
            {
                string resultString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result);
                Console.WriteLine("############BROWSER REQUEST################" + Environment.NewLine + requestString + Environment.NewLine + "############BROWSER REQUEST################");
                Console.WriteLine("############WEBSITE RESPONSE###############" + Environment.NewLine + resultString + Environment.NewLine + "############WEBSITE RESPONSE###############");
                Console.WriteLine("responseLenght: " + result.Length);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Network.Forward() -> " + ex.Message);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

I thought that it should work because I'm just sending raw data from browser to server and back. Again, all the other code works fine because with HTTP websites it works.

this is my console window after sending trying to talk to HTTPS

[image: empty response when trying https]

Comment: Implementing a SOCKS proxy with SSL support is more complicated than this. Check this project I published a lot ago: https://gusnet.codeplex.com more concretely the classes SocksSocket and GusProxyPath on the GusBridge project, there is a full implementation of a SOCKS proxy with SSL support.

Comment: Care to explain why it should be more complicated than that? I mean, I'm just relaying what the browser sends?!?! Doesn't make sense to me why it should be more than that

Comment: You have set-up a proxy on the browser, proxies have their own protocol, check the code I pointed, you will see the differences.

Comment: BTW, I implemented that code a long ago and also struggled with SSL, if I don't explain it better is just because I don't remember exactly where the problem lied XD